# Add delimited text layer is no longer an option in Data Source Manager for QGIS 3.10.6

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a CSV with lat/long coordinates that I wish to turn into a shapefile. The process involves going to Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer. In QGIS 3.4.6, this would open up the Data Source Manager, where on the right-hand column there was a "Delimited Text" option to import a CSV and create a shapefile (First image). I recently installed QGIS 3.10.6, opening Data Source Manager no longer includes a "Delimited Text" option to import a CSV with lat/long coordinates (Second image). Is there a way to add this option to the Data Source Manager? Or do I have to find another way to accomplish this task.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: The option is still there with 3.10.5. Have you checked with the bug reports for QGIS? Have you tried a clean installation? Have you any plugins enabled?

Comment: It is here under 3.10.6 for Windows. The window looks like your 1st one. Note that you are missing much more than the CSV (all the DB, WMS etc)